# How to create an alias for a SQL Server that has changed its name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

My company has used two different SQL Servers, let's call them `SqlServer01` and `SqlServer02`.

But now, we have a fresh new `SqlServer03` that will house all databases that were on `SqlServer01` and `SqlServer02`.

The issue is, however, that `SqlServer01` and `SqlServer02` were each set up as linked servers, so stored procedures could be written that included databases from both servers.

This has worked fine before the migration, but now we are facing an issue. There are hundreds of references to the linked servers in the stored procedures. Those will now all break as they are now housed on one server.

Is there some way to set up an alias so that the stored procedures do not have to be modified?

Is there some other solution to this? Or should a script be written that opens each and every stored procedure and replaces the linked server name?

I have not gone down this road before, and am not sure the best path forward. The new server is actually set up as a SQL Server Cluster.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using an automated script to remove the linked server name, but then make sure you check the syntax before committing

Comment: You can (re)create linked servers with the name of your choosing, which does not need to be the actual server name (e.g. `EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'OLDSERVER', @srvproduct=N'', @provider=N'MSOLEDBSQL', @datasrc=N'NEWSERVER', @catalog=N'YourDatabase'`. That will provide backwards compatibility.

Comment: Surely the benefit of moving all of this to one server is to get away from the linked server queries, therefore correcting the code really should be the solution you're after here.

Comment: I would second the suggestion of scripting replacing/removing references in the SPs. I have implemented this for similar reasons historically you can obtain the SP text from `sys.sql_modules`  or `object_definition(object_id)`

Comment: BTW, I sometimes see people use synonyms so that linked servers can be referenced using 2-part names instead of 4-part names. This way, only the synonyms need be changed instead of every reference.

Answer (score 2):

> Or should a script be written that opens each and every SP and replaces the linked server name?

Yes.  And this is extremely easy.  Just script out all the stored procedures as DROP and CREATE to a new query window in SSMS and search and replace the names and run the resulting script.

[image]

[image]